# PivotTable Field List Error - Current session is no longer valid due to structural changes in the database

Tags: ssas, olap, pivot-table, cube, office-web-components

I have an Analysis Services database. The cube Storage Mode is MOLAP and Proactive Caching is set to Off. All dimensions, measures and partitions have MOLAP set as Storage Mode and Proactive Caching set to Off as well.

When I'm connecting to the cube through Excel or SQL Server Management Studio, everything works great.

But users connect to the cube through web pages. We use Office Web Components. They were working fine until recently, users encounter the below error randomly when filtering dimension, expanding, collapsing, etc...:
Current session is no longer valid due to structural changes in the database

First the PivotTable returns blank. When they try to refresh data, they get the below error message.

[image: Error]

Help.

Thanks,

Mona

Answer (score 0):

If it'is not a huge olap db I recomend process db in full processing mode (not incremental).

Comment: Actually the scheduled job processes the cube in full processing mode. I found that all relationships in dimensions are rigid (not flexible). Could this have anything to do with it?

Comment: In general, you should only use rigid relationships if you are absolutely sure there will not be updates or deletes on the dimension table. An example would be the Date dimension. However, since you mentioned you are doing a successfull full process of the cube then the relationship type should not be the cause of the issue. I would recommand finding out what has changed recently in your environment. Any upgrades to your client tools? cube structural changes? Server changes?

Answer (score 0):

I typically build cubes in this manner: PREFIX_YYYYMMDD.
that way, when I build a new version of the cube, I can still use the old version of the cube.

And then I change the connection strings (from the XmlData method) using a simple UPDATE statement to change the cube name...

Can you revert to a backup, an older version of the cube?

I absolutely LOVE Office Web Components / SSAS.. I think that they are by far the coolest product to every come out of Microsoft.